# Would $v^TAv>0$ forall $v$, $v$ if A's eigenvalues are all > 0?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

I'm learning that if $n \times n$ positive definite matrix A A's  then $\forall v$ $v^TAv>0 \ $,
but this requires A is symmetric(then A have orthonormal eigenvectors)

so I'm asking:

1.if A is not symmetric, but still have n eigenvectors with n positive eigenvalues, would $v^TAv>0 \ $ forall
$v$

2.if A have r eigenvectors (r<n) with r eigenvalues, but all of them are positive, would $v^TAv>0 \ $ forall
$v$

Comment: this answers question 2